# HotRodClientException:Request for message id[6] returned server error (status=0x85): java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan, jgroups, hot-rod

I am new to infinispan and I am trying clustered configuration.
Here is my code

```
GlobalConfigurationBuilder globalConfig = GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder();
globalConfig.transport().clusterName("infiniDistributedCluster").distributedSyncTimeout(30000).globalJmxStatistics().enable().allowDuplicateDomains(Boolean.TRUE);
configBuilder = new org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder();
embeddedCacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(globalConfig.build());
configBuilder.dataContainer().compatibility().enable().clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC).sync().hash().numOwners(2).l1().lifespan(60000);
embeddedCacheManager.defineConfiguration("TestCache", configBuilder.build());

HotRodServerConfiguration build = new HotRodServerConfigurationBuilder().host(hotRodIpAddress).build();
HotRodServer server = new HotRodServer();
server.start(build, embeddedCacheManager);
```

I am trying to fetch it from my HotRod client.

```
ConfigurationBuilder remoteBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
remoteBuilder.addServers(serverIP).nearCache().mode(NearCacheMode.LAZY).maxEntries(500);
RemoteCacheManager remoteCacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(remoteBuilder.build());
remoteCache = remoteCacheManager.getCache("TestCache");
```

But I receive the above exception.

Comment: What Infinispan version? Any chance of showing the line where the NPE is thrown? The Hot Rod client code is tested creating a local Hot Rod server in similar way to what you're doing but dunno what might be different

Comment: It's 7.1.1
As far as I remember I did first get, then put & then again get & I land up this exception

Comment: Can you try with a more recent version? Latest stable is 9.1.2

Comment: I am abide to use 7.1.1 in this product

Comment: Right, I understand that you have to stick to that version, but if you try latest stable, we can see if the issue is still present. If the issue still present, we can work to fix it. If the issue is not present in latest stable, you can debug through the code to see how it works in recent versions and compare with the version you're stuck with ;)

Comment: You could also try to enable TRACE logging, get a full stacktrace (what variable is null? Check the Infinispan JIRA to see if the same stacktrace lines appear somewhere...etc. If you can't move to the latest version, you're going to need to do some digging...